# Exclude the row if the value exists in other column

Tags: mysql, sql

There is my MYSQL table:

[image]

I want to order and test if the value from `num+1` exists in `num`, or the value from `num+2` exists in `num`, or the value from `num+3` field exists in `num`, or the value from `num+4` field exists in `num` - for all rows - then delete the row if true.

expected result:

[image]

My code is:

```
DELETE interface_T.num, interface_T.num+1, interface_T.num+2, interface_T.num+3, interface_T.num+4
FROM interface_T
WHERE (((interface_T.num+1) In (select num from interface_T ))) OR (((interface_T.num+2) In (select num from interface_T ))) OR (((interface_T.num+3) In (select num from interface_T ))) OR (((interface_T.num+4) In (select num from interface_T )));
```

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: I edited the post and placed my code

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
delete t
    from table t join
         table tnext
         on tnext.id in (t.num+1, t.num+2, t.num+3, t.num+4);
```

Comment: but I have only one table " interface_T"

Comment: This is the right answer, what do you mean you "have only one table 'interface_T'"?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

If `num` value is found somewhere else in same row, then `delete` the row.

```
delete from tablename
where num in (`num+1`, `num+2`,`num+3`, `num+4`)
```

Comment: this query delete all rows that contain tested value

Comment: @ImiiIik, is that what you want?

Comment: no I want just delete the line that contain the found value in "num" column

Answer (score 0):

can you please show us the query you used ? did you use the distinct clause? 
try it first and then come and comment

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Should have been a comment instead.

Comment: I tried this code but it delete all rows when the value exists: DELETE FROM interface_T
WHERE (([interface_T].[num+1] In (select num from interface_T ))) OR (([interface_T].[num+2] In (select num from interface_T ))) OR (([interface_T].[num+3] In (select num from interface_T ))) OR (([interface_T].[num+4] In (select num from interface_T )));